# `CalendarView` Is Displayed Differently In Android Studio Emulator & Mobile Application

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a Appointment Application for an assignment, and for this I have to make a `CalendarView` in my android application. However when I run my application the design of the `CalendarView` that is shown in my mobile and the emulator ends up different. **I want the `CalendarView` to show up in my mobile the same way it is displayed in the emulator.**

This is how the `CalendarView` shows up in my mobile:

[image]

This is how the `CalendarView`shows up in the emulator & design view in Android Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Android itself changing the framework's CalendarView between versions, vendors can potentially modify it as well. For consistent behavior you can bundle your own. [Square's TimesSquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) is one reasonable option.

Comment: Yes but I would like to use the default `CalendarView` for this application.

Comment: @MoizMansoorAli Unfortunately that's impossible then.

Comment: Ok then I will have to try it out with a different API Version.

Answer (score 0):

the theme of this widget can change from api to api

try to set a theme in the xml.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: I tried the above code but I still get the same output on my Mobile Device. Note: The mobile is running on android 5.1 Lollipop and the emulator is running on Nougat. Does this make a difference?